# Create an alphabet in PHP with only some letters depending of names in database

Tags: php, mysql, alphabet

I have a database (SQL) with a lot of names and I'd like to create alphabetical buttons so it's easy to navigate. I've found lots of examples on how to create an alphabet in PHP. However, I want to build an alphabet with only valid letters depending on the names on the database.

For example:

The database lists: Anderson, Beresford, Donovan, Emerson, Graham....

I'd like the alphabet to appear as: A B D E G ...

(Notice that C and F do not appear).

The only way I can think of is to

-select every name in the database, 
-order by last name 
-loop one by one, find what the first character is, save it to an array, 
-loop to the second one, get the first character, see if it already exists in the array and if it does ignore it
-do this on and on until I'm left with an array of only unrepeated letters.

Is this the only way? Or am I missing a simpler solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use LEFT(colName, 1) to return just the first char from a column.  I'm not sure how the best way to use this to get just the alphabet would be... maybe SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(colName, 1) or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(lastname,1,1) 'initial'
FROM people
ORDER BY initial ASC
```

Bear in mind that this is a string operation on every row in the database, followed by an unindexed sort operation. It will *not* perform well at all once the table becomes large.

Comment: OP might want to write an array_filter function or similar to do the processing on PHP's end if there is a lot of load on the DB.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be a simpler method.

Comment: I was about to ask a question similar to the thread. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LEFT(name, 1) AS firstletter 
FROM database 
GROUP BY firstletter
ORDER BY last_name
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your names hav already been pulled into an array you can use something like this (quick and dirty, maybe overkill for what you want/need, but works!)...

```
<?php

$names = array('Anderson','Beresford','Donovan','Emerson','Graham');

$alphabet = array();
$previous_letter = '';

foreach($names as $value) {
  if($value[0] != $previous_letter) {
    $alphabet[] = $previous_letter = $value[0];
  }
}

print_r($alphabet);

?>
```

Working example here: http://3v4l.org/VT0Rt